# JavaScript - how to add support for document.all for other browsers?

Tags: javascript

I have got a bunch of old Javascript code, where `document.all` is used. So now, I need to find a way to replace `document.all` with `document.getElementById`. Is there are anything that I could do to encapsulate `document.all`, so it will call second function instead? Or do I need to edit all files?

Comment: It would be much easier, in the long run, if you just replaced it. Don't underestimate the power of Find/Replace of your text editor.

Comment: Just bite the bullet and replace it. `document.all` has been obsolete for a very *very* long time.

Comment: `document.all` seems to still exist (and work) in Google Chrome.

Comment: I don't think that this code will be used in future. It will be replaced with framework functionality and new js-code. But for now I need to implement old links to work in framework dialog window, so I need to replace this thing.

Comment: it should be a relatively simple search+replace. The only big "gotcha" is that the old `document.all` can sometimes respond to an elements' `name` attribute as well as the `id`. But if you've using it in that context, you can resolve it by making sure that any elements with a `name` have a matching `id`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - some modern browsers do implement `document.all` for backward compatibility reasons. But not all of them, and they generally try to restrict its use by pretending it doesn't exist if you try to feature detect it (they have to do that because a lot of old sites used detection of `document.all` to detect IE, and you wouldn't want all your IE-specific hacks to be run in Chrome)

Comment: @Spudley: That's weird.  `!document.all` is `true` in Chrome.  So it *is* pretending it doesn't exist :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Strangely, `typeof document.all` is "undefined" in Chrome, which seems to be [against the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3).

Comment: @bfavaretto: Someone doesn't want you to know that "feature" exists ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!document.all) {
    document.constructor.prototype.__defineGetter__('all', function() { 
        return document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What about usage such as `document.all['header']`?

Comment: (and by the above I mean "header" as an id or name, not a tag name)